# Compiling ROS Kinetec from source fails when building opencv

Tags: opencv, ros

I'm using an Arch machine and trying to compile **ROS desktop full** from source. The build fails when **image_proc** is trying to link executable.

Here is the error log:

```
[ 23%] Built target image_proc_gencfg
[ 84%] Built target image_proc
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable /home/alphayed/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_proc/lib/image_proc/image_proc
/home/alphayed/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libopencv_viz3.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `vtkSTLReader::New()'
/home/alphayed/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libopencv_viz3.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `vtkOBJReader::New()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/image_proc_exe.dir/build.make:219: /home/alphayed/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_proc/lib/image_proc/image_proc] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/image_proc_exe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:139: all] Error 2
```

I think the problem is related to **opencv3**. I removed it from the system and recompiled it from source but that didn't solve the issue. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix as per this [thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/250846/compiling-ros-kinetec-from-source-fails-when-building-image_proc/). You need to modify `opencv3/cmake/OpenCVDetectVTK.cmake`, for every `find_package(VTK QUIET COMPONENTS ...` add an entry `vtkIOGeometry`